# How to always get latest version of JS CSS on your ASPX page?

Tags: javascript, css

I came across an issue where I am deploying the new build for my website and the expected new look of the site is all gone due to old CSS & JS files still in users browser cache.

Searching through the web gave me a lot of solution, however, each one required a lot of effort of changing the links in each of the ASPX / ASCX and other files where the CSS & JS files are to be used.

There was no generic solution available where I can just call the code once and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt a strong need for some generic code that would resolve my issue once and forever and with minimal effort.

I wrote a simple extension which goes as below:

```
  public static class PageExtension
{   
 public static IList<T> GetAllControlsRecursive<T>(this Control control) where T : Control
    {
        var rtn = new List<T>();
        foreach (Control item in control.Controls)
        {
            var ctr = item as T;
            if (ctr != null)
            {
                rtn.Add(ctr);
            }
            if (item.HasChildren())
            {
                rtn.AddRange(GetAllControlsRecursive<T>(item));
            }

        }
        return rtn;
    }     
    public static void SetPageLinks(this Control page)
    {
        if (page is Page p | page is MasterPage mp | page is UserControl uc)
        {
            var listLinks = page.GetAllControlsRecursive<HtmlLink>();
            foreach (var link in listLinks)
            {
                link.Attributes["href"] = $"{page.ResolveUrl(link.Attributes["href"])}?v={ MyAppConstant.GetVersion}";
            }
            var listServerLinks = page.GetAllControlsRecursive<HtmlGenericControl>();
            foreach(var link in listServerLinks)
            {
                if(link.Attributes["href"] !=null && !link.Attributes["href"].Contains(MyAppConstant.GetVersion))
                {
                    link.Attributes["href"] = $"{page.ResolveUrl(link.Attributes["href"])}?v={ MyAppConstant.GetVersion}";
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

After adding PageExtension to my web application, I just need to call the method once in Page_Load of Master Page or Page and I am done.

Please feel free to improve my code and do share your comments on the same.